# Iphone and jquery issue

Tags: jquery, iphone

I have an issue which exists only on the iPhone. I have two text field say name and age and a button "save" to save the contents entered in the text field. In addition to this, delete and edit functions are also present. When I try to save the text contents after modifying, the changes are not getting updated on the iPhone. The code snippet for edit is given below:

`function editDriver(dCount,indx){
    $('#YoungDriverName'+indx).val($('#dName'+dCount).val());
    $('#YoungDriverId'+indx).val($('#dId'+dCount).val());
    $('#drivereditId').val(dCount);
    $('#savedriverbtn'+indx).text("Update");`enter code here
`}`

Any info on why the data is not getting updated will be of help to me.

Comment: Can you check if the jquery code used for update is supported in safari.

Comment: s I have checked in safari in latest version its working